# One MongoDB instance in a two or more replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication

is it possible to have One mongodb instance belong to one or more replica sets ?

I am using Replica Set - mongodb replication scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

With Master-Slave you could hack this to make it work, but not with Replica Sets. However, you can run two instances on a single machine. Simply run them on different ports.

Please note that this is generally not advised. If you are sharing replicas, this typically means that you do not have enough hardware.